# Issue Migrating DB to Heroku - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

For starters I am using two different dbs, sqlite in development and postgresql in production.

I think the issue is related to forgetting to constantly migrate to heroku after changes to my db. I probably did four or five migrations locally before migrating on heroku. So anyways, the issue is that when i tun `heroku run rails db:migrate` I get an error saying `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist` although in development it definitely does. I'll try and attach all the necessary info below. Let me know if anything is missing.

schema.rb

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161011053831) do

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

The terminal output

```
Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ [retracted]... up, run.1231 (Free)
D, [2016-10-11T06:15:07.562673 #3] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(6976026441189414000);
D, [2016-10-11T06:15:07.572811 #3] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
I, [2016-10-11T06:15:07.577534 #3]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateComments (20160928024026)
D, [2016-10-11T06:15:07.579481 #3] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  BEGIN
== 20160928024026 CreateComments: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:comments)
D, [2016-10-11T06:15:07.594892 #3] DEBUG -- :    (13.9ms)  CREATE TABLE "comments" ("id" serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "body" text, "blog_post_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_03de2dc08c"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_29c545254e"
FOREIGN KEY ("blog_post_id")
  REFERENCES "blog_posts" ("id")
)
D, [2016-10-11T06:15:07.595917 #3] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2016-10-11T06:15:07.597131 #3] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(6976026441189414000)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "comments" ("id" serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "body" text, "blog_post_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_03de2dc08c"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_29c545254e"
FOREIGN KEY ("blog_post_id")
  REFERENCES "blog_posts" ("id")
)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:97:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:283:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20160928024026_create_comments.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `migrate_without_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1298:in `with_advisory_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "comments" ("id" serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "body" text, "blog_post_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_03de2dc08c"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_29c545254e"
FOREIGN KEY ("blog_post_id")
  REFERENCES "blog_posts" ("id")
)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:97:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:283:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20160928024026_create_comments.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `migrate_without_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1298:in `with_advisory_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:98:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:97:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:283:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:845:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:814:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:834:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20160928024026_create_comments.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:788:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1211:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1279:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1210:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1183:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1182:in `migrate_without_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1298:in `with_advisory_lock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1131:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:983:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:161:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've tried a few other solutions floating around but nothing so far has worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are creating `comments` table before `users`, and while using `user_id` foreign key in `comments` table it fails, because there is no such table yet.

Make sure your migrations ordered correctly (users, then comments).

And generally, you should always first create tables/columns, and only after they are created and migrated, reference them.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I took a look and I see what you're saying. I'm not really sure how to reorder my migrations though? Does that involve changing the timestamp in the file name?

Comment: @jamesemcc yea, changing timestamp in the file name would perfectly work. But make sure to rollback the database, or, if there is no important data, you can just drop it. 1. `rake db:drop` 2. reorder migrations 3. `rake db:create && rake db:migrate`

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try when I have a chance. Is there much relevance to the exact times I change for the time stamp or is it mainly just about being in order?

Comment: Sorry and one more question, I will probably just drop the db because there's not important data but if I were to rollback I would have to rollback to the beginning considering that it is my first migration right?

Comment: @jamesemcc yea, it is exclusively about keeping order. If you drop the db no need to rollback, but yes, if you'd select rolling back, you'd have to rollback down until migrations you want to change are undone.

Comment: I followd your advice, although since I have a different db in production I looked for the same method with postgreSQL and heroku but it worked! So thanks for the guidance.